# UIContextualAction with icon AND clear background in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I use the following code

```
  let deleteAction =
   UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: ""){ (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in

            self.dataManager.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.itemCardTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            completionHandler(true)
    }

let deleteResize = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "delete72").resizeImage(withSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50), scaleMode: .contentAspectFill)
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: deleteResize!)
```

image is repeated. This is not what I want

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUUWY.png

I want is like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV5DX.png

How to fix it

Comment: show your code of  `UISwipeActionsConfiguration`

Comment: try with `scaleMode: .contentAspectFit`

Comment: scaleMode: .contentAspectFit is not working

Comment: Please do not post image of your code, post your code!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `UIColor(patternImage: deleteResize!)`, instead use the `image` property of the `UIContextualAction` instance.

To get a truly `.clear` background has been solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51939297/5058116, but appears very messy ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you set background color with **alpha = 0.**

```
      let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Delete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
                  //TODO: 
        })
      deleteAction.backgroundColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0)
```