# How to set clear background in table view cell swipe action?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a trailingSwipeAction in a UITableViewCell, whose background color must be clear.

This is the code where I set the action :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let myAction = UIContextualAction.init(style: .normal, title: nil) {
        // My action code
    }
    myAction.backgroundColor = .clear
    myAction.image = UIImage.init(named: "my-icon")
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration.init(actions: [myAction])
}
```

But I am getting gray background for the action, when no color was expected:

[image]

Comment: Clear color - means fully transparent. So you need to check background colors of views which are under your button (TableViewCell, TableView etc...)

Comment: Still gray, thank you anyway.

Comment: have you set the tableView.backgroundColor = .clear in the viewdidload method ?

Comment: Yes, tableview background is clear and everything behind the cell and the cell to clear too. And it still appears gray

Comment: and the cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear ?

Comment: Yes, everything. I will try what Carpsen90 says,  here I have found some info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46716229/not-able-find-uitableviewcelldeleteconfirmationview-in-ios-11-layoutsubview-subv/46721607#46721607

Comment: @Sergio don’t use UILabel in the last if-condition. Use UIImage or UIImageView. Please read the code and comments carefully.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just set the alpha value to 0 for background color of the action:

```
let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
    print("Update action ...")
    success(true)
})
modifyAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 0.0)
```

Comment: It's true. Doesn't work with UIColor.clear but it does with UIColor.init(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 0.0) and also with UIColor.init(white: 1, alpha: 0). Thanks, I accept your answer as valid! :)

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to access the UIView inside the `UIActionStandardButton` inside the `UISwipeActionPullView`. and then change its background color.

[image: pull view hierarchy]

You can see the view hierarchy of your app swiping on a cell, then going the `Debug` menu in Xcode, then `View Debugging`, and choose `Capture View Hierarchy`.

First of all, let add this useful [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39603570/2907715) that gets all subviews and their subviews in an array:

```
extension UIView {
    var allSubViews : [UIView] {
        var array = [self.subviews].flatMap {$0}
        array.forEach { array.append(contentsOf: $0.allSubViews) }
        return array
    }
}
```

And then in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    let btn = tableView
              .allSubViews //get all the subviews
              .first(where: {String(describing:type(of: $0)) ==  "UISwipeActionStandardButton"}) // get the first one that is a UISwipeActionStandardButton

    //This UISwipeActionStandardButton has two subviews, I'm getting the one that is not a UILabel, in your case, since you've set the image,  you should get the one that is not an imageView
    if let view = btn?.subviews.first(where: { !($0 is UILabel)})
    {
        view.backgroundColor = .clear //Change the background color of the gray uiview
    }
}
```

I am using `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` since it's called to notify the view controller that its view is about to layout its subviews. Have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621437-viewwilllayoutsubviews) for more details.

This solution is optimized for one swipe action button. If you have more than one button, the code would look like this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    let buttons = tableView
        .allSubViews //get all the subviews
        .filter {String(describing:type(of: $0)) ==  "UISwipeActionStandardButton"}

    buttons.forEach { btn in
        if let view = btn.subviews.first(where: { !($0 is UIImageView)}) //If you're sure that other than the uiview there is a UIImageView in the subviews of the UISwipeActionStandardButton
        {
            view.backgroundColor = .clear //Change the background color of the gray uiview
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, I can't find the way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: I will try with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46716229/not-able-find-uitableviewcelldeleteconfirmationview-in-ios-11-layoutsubview-subv/46721607#46721607

Comment: @Sergio The post that you are referring to uses Xamarin. I've updated my answer. I hope helps.

Comment: Still not working, we better continue the conversation by chat.

Comment: @Sergio what did you use instead of UILabel?

Comment: I have a custom cell class that extends UITableViewCell, that only contains a  UILabel.

Comment: @Sergio That’s not what I meant. Please have a look at the hierarchy of the UISwipeActionPullView. In my test project it contains a UISwipeActionStandardButton. Which contains a UIView (that is responsible for the grey background) and a UILabel. The code snippet above looks for the UIView (not the UILabel). I’m not talking about the rest of the cell. In your case since you’re setting the image for the action, you should use UIImageView or UIImage in the last if-condition. Please read my answer carefully, I hope it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178470/discussion-between-sergio-and-carpsen90).

Comment: @Sergio I did join the chat

Answer (score 6):

### SOLUTION

Thanks to **Carpsen90**

[image]

You have to set the backgroundColor of that UIImageView to .clear, but it doesn't exist in the time of viewWillLayoutSubviews. It is created after you swipe.

A posible solution is to have a Timer:

```
var timerCellSwipeButtons: Timer?
```

Launched when the swipe is done:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let editAction = UIContextualAction.init(style: .normal, title: nil) { [weak self] (action, view, completion) in
        // editAction code
    }
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction.init(style: .normal, title: nil) { [weak self] (action, view, completion) in
        // deleteAction code
    }
    // Set the button's images
    editAction.image = UIImage.init(named: "editIcon")
    deleteAction.image = UIImage.init(named: "deleteIcon")
    // You also must set the background color of the actions to .clear
    editAction.backgroundColor = .clear
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .clear
    // Launch the timer, that will run a function every 10 milliseconds
    self.timerCellSwipeButtons = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(timerCellSwipeButtonsFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Return the actions
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration.init(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
}
```

Now every 10 milliseconds (you can increase the frequency if you want), this function checks the tableView subviews looking for all the UISwipeActionStandardButton and setting to .clear the backgroundColor of their UIView:

```
@objc func timerCellSwipeButtonsFunction() {
    // Gets all the buttons, maybe we have more than one in a row
    let buttons = tableView.allSubViews.filter { (view) -> Bool in
        String(describing: type(of: view)) == "UISwipeActionStandardButton"
    }
    // Loops through all the buttons
    for button in buttons {
        if let view = button.subviews.first(where: { !($0 is UIImageView)})
        {
            // We are interested in the UIView that isn't a UIImageView
            view.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
    // When finish, timer is invalidated because we don't need it anymore.
    // A new one will be launched with every swipe
    self.timerCellSwipeButtons?.invalidate()
}
```

To get all the subviews of a UIView, I used the function given by **Carpsen90**:

```
extension UIView {
    var allSubViews : [UIView] {
        var array = [self.subviews].flatMap {$0}
        array.forEach { array.append(contentsOf: $0.allSubViews) }
        return array
    }
}
```

For safety reasons, you should also invalidate the timer in the viewWillDisappear method:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.timerCellSwipeButtons?.invalidate()
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

But as you can see, when you have more than one action in the same side of the cell and you swipe completely, doesn't look very nice:

[image]

To avoid icons overlapping I put only one action in each side:

```
// Remember to launch the timer in both swipe functions, like in the example above

// Function to add actions to the leading side of the cell
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
// Function to add actions to the trailing side of the cell
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Apparently if you set the background color to white with zero alpha, it will stay clear but without the gray default color.

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { [weak self] (action, view, completion) in
        // weak self to prevent memory leak if needed
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        // do your nasty stuff here 
        
        completion(true)
    }
    
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")
    
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

100% working in iOS swift for change swipe button image color and background color change.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    if isInbox {
        let action =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
            self.selectedIndex  = indexPath.row
            self.deleteNotification()
            completionHandler(true)

        })
        let cgImageX =  UIImage(named: "delete-1")?.cgImage
        action.image = OriginalImageRender(cgImage: cgImageX!)
        action.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "F7F7F7")
        let confrigation = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])

        return confrigation
    }
    return nil
}
```

Add this Class also for original image color display otherwise its showing only white image

```
class OriginalImageRender: UIImage {
    override func withRenderingMode(_ renderingMode: UIImage.RenderingMode) -> UIImage {
        return self
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I only a black icon that was larger. action.backgroundColor just changed the background color...not unexpected.

Comment: @TiloDelau which type output you want please tell me i can help you

Comment: Well, I want to change the icon color. This is my (modified) code from you, but I just get the bigger sized black icon with a blue background (actually want a clear background). I guess because its not actually an image?:         let cgImageX = UIImage(systemName: "minus.square")?.cgImage
        delete.image = OriginalImageRender(cgImage: cgImageX!)
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        let confrigation = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
        return confrigation

Comment: please check @TiloDelau if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                action.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)).image { _ in
                    UIImage(systemName: "minus.square")?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
                }
                action.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 0.0)
                let confrigation = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
                return confrigation
            } else {
                
            }

Comment: Can adjust the size, but icon color is still black:if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            delete.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).image {
                _ in UIImage(systemName: "minus.square")?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
                
            }
            delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 244/255.0, alpha: 0)
            let confrigation = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
            return confrigation
            
            
        } else { ...

Comment: And Im on iOS 14. I added blue: 244/255.0 because I wanted it blue. But 0/255 doesn't matter either. Icon same black color.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in my project is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let subViews = tableView.subviews.filter { (view) -> Bool in
      if NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder) == "UISwipeActionPullView" {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    if subViews.count > 0 {
        let bgView = subViews[0]
        bgView.backgroundColor = bgColor
    }
}
```

And my project's target is iOS 9.0 and above

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution from @Maulik Patel I just added a tint color option to the action.image:

```
let imageDelete = UIImage(systemName: "trash")?.cgImage
deleteAction.image = OriginalImageRender(cgImage: imageDelete!).withTintColor(UIColor(named: ("colorButton"))!)
deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 0.0)      
        
let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
        
return configuration
```